# How do I add a transition to my navbar menu in react when I click the toggle button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have created an e-commerce base template in HTML and CSS / Bootstrap. I am trying to convert the template to React components for a NextJS site, but the toggle function was not initially working. I saw I can use React Hooks to toggle classes, which I have implemented using useState/isActive. The hamburger transition works but the transition for the actual menu does not.

Here is navbar.js

```
import Logo from '../images/logo-small-cropped.png'
import Image from 'next/image'
import React, { useState } from "react"

export default function Navbar({ }) {
  
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");
    const handleToggle = () => {
      setActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light border-top fixed-top border-bottom py-0" >
            <div className="container-fluid text-center" >
              <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <span className="mb-2">
                  <Image src={Logo} alt="Little Pink Boutique Logo"  />
                </span>
              </a>
              <button onClick={handleToggle} className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-button" type="button" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <div id="hamburger" className={isActive ? "null" : "open"}>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                </div>
              </button>
           
              <div className={isActive ? "collapse navbar-collapse" : "navbar-collapse"}  >
                <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/home" > </a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Women</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Men</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Children</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Accessories</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">FAQs</a>
                  </li>
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
     
                </ul>
                <form className="d-flex">
                  <input className="form-control me-2 mt-3 mb-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
                  <button className="btn btn-outline-success mt-3 mb-2" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
              </div>
             
              
            </div>
          </nav>  
      )
    }
```

The .collapse class is just the standard Bootstrap class, the navbar-collapse class is as follows.

```
.navbar-collapse{
  background-color: rgb(238, 236, 236);
  width: 100vw;
}
```

I'm not sure how to get the transition to work, or if this is the best way to do it.

Any help appreciated as always.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the transition css property in the navbar-collapse class.
Something like this :-

```
.navbar-collapse{
  transition: width 2s;
  background-color: rgb(238, 236, 236);
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: I tried the transition property already and it didn't do anything :-(. The toggle was originally controlled by the data-bs-target and data-bs-toggle html attributes but they did not work inside the react components, so I attempted to add the transition property and that also did not work

Comment: In your useState the value of isActive is set to string. What is the value of isActive after toggle ?

Comment: I don't know I just scrapped it and did it again using Bootstrap React and everything was fine! Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. The above code looks fine as well, just replace `const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");` to `const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);` and it should work as well.